# Proper treatment of roots and powers in Series?

Tags: syntax, series-expansion

I have the following problem in *Mathematica* 9 on Linux. I let *Mathematica* compute the `Series` expansion:

```
Block[{$Assumptions = {r, p}\[Element] Reals}, 
      Series[Log[r^2 - Sqrt[r^4 + p^2]], {p, 0, 0}]
]
```

But the output is a rather disappointing naked infinity:

```
Log[r^2 - Sqrt[r^4]] + O[p]^1
```

Similarly, for:

```
Block[{$Assumptions = {p, r} \[Element] Reals}, 
      Series[1/(r^2 - Sqrt[r^4 + p^2]), {p, 0, 0}]
]
```

I get:

```
1/(r^2 - Sqrt[r^4]) + O[p]^1
```

Why is *Mathematica* handing me naked infinities like that, even though I specified that the computation is to be carried out in the real numbers? What do I do wrong? How can I avoid this?

EDIT:

To make my point more clear, I would expect the Series to give results like
$$\log(c_1 p^2)+O(p^1)$$
and
$$\frac{1}{c_2 p^2}+O(p^1)$$
as a regulated infinity, instead of $\log(0)$ and $\frac{1}{0}$.

Comment: Are you disappointed about the output or do you think it's not correct ?

Comment: I am disappointed, since the Series function should give a regulated infinity, like $\frac{1}{p^2}$ or something, instead of a mathematically nonsensical $\frac{1}{0}$.

Comment: I have been told, that as a quick solution one can substitute r by ie Zeta[5]. Any zeta of odd numbers greater than 1 will do. After the expansion is done one simply has to substitute back.

Comment: Not a full-fledged answer, Mathematica's behaviour still puzzles me, but something that may point you in the right direction: you do get the expected result if you assume *r>0 && p>0*. The assumption *r<0 && p>0* works too, but *(r<0 || r>0) && p>0* does not...

Comment: It looks like some time between 12.0.1 and 12.3.1 Mathematica started returning your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, mathematically: Series is a central instrument in complex analysis and has no real version.  The series aquired formally e.g. by using Taylors formula, if all derivatives are computable, defines a complex analytic function in an open circle in the complex plane, that touches the nearest singularity anywhere, where the series diverges.

Standard example is the function

```
f[x_]:=(1-x^2)^(-1)
```

that has a geometric series representation.
f[z_]:= Sum[x^(2n) ,{n,0,oo}] | z | < 1

Here the nearest singularities are simple poles in the points z= +-I, while along  the real axis the function is perfectly smooth. But smoothness on the real axis does not yield a series , representationas the this classical example is showing:

```
x-> Exp[-1/x^2]  \el {0,1}
```

is a real function with all derivatives 0 at x=0. The function has a real power series

```
sum 0 z^n.
```

The reason is that for z on the imaginary axis there is no value at z->0. The real line as a smooth path through the complex hell at z=0

```
ComplexPlot3D[ Exp[-1/z^2], {z, -(1 + 0.2 I), (1 + 0.2 I)} , 
       PlotRange -> {0, 50}, ViewPoint -> {7, 1, 5}, ImageSize -> 220]
```

[image: essential singularity]

Comment: You have "Series" as the first word in a sentence, so I do not know if you mean Taylor series in general, or the Mathematica function `Series`. If the latter, the rest is not really accurate, because it takes assumptions that are intended to allow for `Piecewise` or other conditional results. `Series` also tries to provide results that behave on branch cuts, results with asymptotic terms and various other extensions to basic Taylor series.